# Why my directives don't work in Plunker?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, plunker

I was going to use Plunker to assist me in testing a directive, but first I just wanted to create one to test plunker was working, so I put in some sample code. Guess what, basic directives are not working and I have no idea why.

My directives:

```
app.directive('attributeDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked attributeDirective');
      });
      iElement.bind('mouseover', function() {
        iElement.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});

app.directive('elementDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<h2>this is elementDirective</h2>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {

      iElement.bind('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked elementDirective');
      });
      iElement.bind('mouseover', function() {
        iElement.css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

My html:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

<h2 attributeDirective>Here is my attribute directive</h2>

<elementDirective></elementDirective>

</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/H9vPhV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while calling a directive in `html` you should replace`camelcase` in directives name like this,

`<element-directive></element-directive>` and not as it is,

`<elementDirective></elementDirective>`

like you did.

Hope this helps!!!

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/mDdb27iih6deGayQ0s3y?p=preview)

[*see through the custom directives here*](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31001134/how-to-create-network-graph-or-hierarchical-tree-using-visjs-in-angularjs) in here my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKfNdsw9g9aCG6wZsQNZ?p=preview) is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
<h2 attribute-directive>Here is my attribute directive</h2>
```

See  http://plnkr.co/edit/2aGGDRw6SdYNc1joSVI1?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Common problem - you can't use camel case in your HTML element declaration.

Try `<element-directive></element-directive>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `restrict: 'A'` in your directive to refer to attribute.
Use `restrict: 'E'` in your directive to refer to element.

Find the plunkr: "http://plnkr.co/edit/b1cf6l?p=preview"

Also call your directive using:

```
<h2 attribute-directive>Here is my attribute directive</h2>   
<element-directive></element-directive>
```