# How to create network graph or hierarchical tree using visjs in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, plunker, vis.js

I need some help in creating a network graph using [visjs](http://visjs.org/) in angularjs. I am working on [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKfNdsw9g9aCG6wZsQNZ?p=preview) to achieve something like [this](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/nodeLegend.html)

I followed the steps mentioned in [AngularJS - visjs](https://github.com/visjs/angular-visjs) but was unable to make it work so I created a plunker (given above) to get help from community.

Controller code.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngVis']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'VisDataSet',

  function($scope, VisDataSet) {
      $scope.data = VisDataSet({
          "1": {
              "id": 1,
              "content": "<i class=\"fi-flag\"></i> item 1",
              "start": "2014-09-01T17:59:13.706Z",
              "className": "magenta",
              "type": "box"
          },
          "2": {
              "id": 2,
              "content": "<a href=\"http://visjs.org\" target=\"_blank\">visjs.org</a>",
              "start": "2014-09-02T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "box"
          },
          "3": {
              "id": 3,
              "content": "item 3",
              "start": "2014-08-29T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "box"
          },
          "4": {
              "id": 4,
              "content": "item 4",
              "start": "2014-09-01T17:59:13.706Z",
              "end": "2014-09-03T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "range"
          },
          "5": {
              "id": 5,
              "content": "item 5",
              "start": "2014-08-30T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "point"
          },
          "6": {
              "id": 6,
              "content": "item 6",
              "start": "2014-09-04T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "point"
          },
          "7": {
              "id": 7,
              "content": "<i class=\"fi-anchor\"></i> item 7",
              "start": "2014-08-28T17:59:13.706Z",
              "end": "2014-08-29T17:59:13.706Z",
              "type": "range",
              "className": "orange"
          }
      });
      $scope.options = {
          "align": "center",
          "autoResize": true,
          "editable": true,
          "selectable": true,
          "orientation": "bottom",
          "showCurrentTime": true,
          "showCustomTime": true,
          "showMajorLabels": true,
          "showMinorLabels": true
      };
  }
]);
```

Please help me in figuring out the problem in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKfNdsw9g9aCG6wZsQNZ?p=preview)

Comment: is there any console error?

Comment: @pankajparkar: I am not getting any error in console. I have posted a continued [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019327/need-help-in-creating-network-graph-using-visjs-in-angularjs). Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a few issues. First, you were including your css files as scripts instead of as stylesheets. So use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.3.0/vis.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Second if you take a look at angular-vis.js, you'll see that the directive should actually be vis-timeline. So I just changed it to this in the html:

```
<vis-timeline data="data" options="options"></vis-timeline>
```

I removed the events attribute because that wasn't defined on your scope, but I assume you can look at the visjs documentation to see what should go there.

See the revised [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0mclPNi4FiTENWnQQK1P?p=info) for the whole fix.

Comment: Thanks plunker works now, will change it to network view for my actual problem. Also, how are you saying that angular-vis.js has `vis-timeline` directive. I see the directive name is `visTimeline`. Please help me understand, I think I am missing something as i am new to angularjs

Comment: it's an angular.js naming convention. See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503121/name-conventions-in-angualrjs-directives

Comment: Need your help in having a zoom in zoom out buttons for visjs in angularjs. I have asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078184/how-to-add-zoom-in-zoom-out-buttons-in-visjs-using-angularjs). Please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Need your help with this question please : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421653/content-items-wont-display-angular-vis-js