# Need help in creating network graph using visjs in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, plunker, vis.js

I need help in making [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LQidVPnOSLhyydsoTwD?p=preview) work something similar to [this vis example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/exampleApplications/nodeLegend.html) in angularjs.

I am using `<vis-network data="data" options="options"></vis-network>` tag and below data and options

data

```
var nodes = [
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
];
var edges = [
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5}
];
$scope.data = VisDataSet({
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
});
```

options

```
$scope.options = {
  autoResize: true,
  height: '100%',
  width: '100%'
};
```

There is no console error, what am I missing. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

Your data is plain object, however `nodes` & `edges` should be an object of `VisDataSet`

```
var nodes = VisDataSet([
  {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
  {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
  {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
  {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
  {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
]);
var edges = VisDataSet([
  {from: 1, to: 3},
  {from: 1, to: 2},
  {from: 2, to: 4},
  {from: 2, to: 5}
]);
$scope.data = {
  nodes: nodes,
  edges: edges
};
```

I have updated your [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LQidVPnOSLhyydsoTwD?p=preview).