# How to add zoom in zoom out buttons in visjs using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, vis.js, vis.js-network

Need help in having a zoom in and zoom out button in [visjs network graph](http://visjs.org/docs/network/) using angularjs, I could not find any relevant options for this. Please help, I am also providing a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/0LQidVPnOSLhyydsoTwD?p=preview) as an example

Code

```
<vis-network data="data" options="options" height="100%"></vis-network>

$scope.options = {
  autoResize: true,
  height: '800',
  width: '100%'
};
```

Comment: You can zoom in and out with the scroll wheel -- why do you need separate buttons to do this?

Comment: @efeder: All users might not have a mouse with scrolls, also some might be using laptops where user might prefer some controls over this graph. Take a look at this [visjs example](http://tiddlymap.org/)

Comment: I have provided a solution similar to [http://tiddlymap.org/](http://tiddlymap.org/) example

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [interaction, navigationButtons](http://visjs.org/docs/network/interaction.html) option. It has built in controls for zoom, pan and reset view.

You need to change your vis options to include `navigationButtons: true` and `keyboard: true` to have keboard shortcuts enabled

```
$scope.options = {
  autoResize: true,
  height: '600',
  width: '100%',
  interaction: {
      navigationButtons: true,
      keyboard: true
  }
};
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fvrBkRUA1aTRerg7VZRt?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I've never worked with plunker, so I can not integrated my solution into your example, but I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4h9xdud/) for it which is based on a simple network example from the visjs.org website.

Unfortunately there is no `setScale(scale)` method available right now, but you could extend the `network` until someone implements it.

```
var network;
var zoomstep = 0.3;

function zoomin() {
    network.setScale(network.getScale() - zoomstep);
}

function zoomout() {
    network.setScale(network.getScale() + zoomstep);
}

vis.Network.prototype.setScale = function (scale) {
    var options = {
        nodes: []
    };
    var range = this.view._getRange(options.nodes);
    var center = this.view._findCenter(range);
    var animationOptions = {
        position: center,
        scale: scale,
        animation: options.animation
    };
    this.view.moveTo(animationOptions);
};
```

The `vis.Network.setScale` code was taken from the Network.js and View.js source code, based on what `getScale()` did. I had to redo some things which the methods `View.fit`, `View._getRange` and `View._findCenter` did but it's working good so far.

Comment: Thanks looks great, but I wanted help in Angularjs can you please provide me the solution using Angularjs?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used Angularjs. Can't give you a good solution with that. But it should not be too difficult for you to put my code into your angularjs application - now that you know how to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am new to angularjs, so I wanted to get a solution in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution for vis.js 4.21.0

```
vis.Network.prototype.zoom = function (scale) {
    const animationOptions = {
        scale: this.getScale() + scale,
        animation: { duration: 300 }
    };
    this.view.moveTo(animationOptions);
};
```

Click handler code:

```
this.network.zoom(-0.5) // or 0.5 to zoom in
```